# .net mvc dropdownlist selected value not being updated

Tags: entity-framework, html-select

I have two models defined as follows:

```
public class Division
{
    public int DivisionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Contact{ set;get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeID{ get; set; }
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public virtual Division Division{set;get;}
}
```

Entity framework sets a field in division table called `employee_employeeid`, how can I create dropdown for employees for the contact attribute in the division table.

Here is what I have tried but nothing is being sent to the database.

```
ViewBag.contact = new SelectList(db.Employees,"EmployeeID","Name");
```

In the view I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("contact",String.Empty)
```

Is there a naming convention I have to use?

**Edit**

POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Division division)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(division).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.employeeid = new SelectList(
        db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeFirstName", division.employee);

    return View(division);
}
```

Comment: How do you update the division in the database?

Comment: `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Division division)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(division).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.employeeid = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeFirstName", division.employee);
            return View(division);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend actually using `ViewData` instead of the ViewBag. In your controller have the following:

```
var employees = db.Employees.Select(e => new DropDownItem{ Text = e.Name, Value = e.EmployeeID });
ViewData["Employees"] = employees;
```

Then, in your view, have the following to display it:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Contact", ((IEnumerable<DropDownItem>)(ViewData["Employees"])))
```

Comment: Why is `ViewData` favored over `ViewBag`?

Comment: That way you don't have to worry about a dynamic variable possibly giving you problems. Plus you can very easily call `.ContainsKey()` on it to make sure that that key is present in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you expose a foreign key property in your model. It makes the binding to the dropdown list and the later update much easier. Your `Division` model would look like this:

```
public class Division
{
    public int DivisionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContactId { set;get; }
    public virtual Employee Contact { set;get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the Edit GET action you fill the `ViewBag` as you did:

```
ViewBag.Contacts = new SelectList(
    db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "Name", division.ContactId);
```

You have a strongly typed view with the `Division` as model:

```
@model MyNamespace.Division
```

In this view you can bind the dropdown list to the `ContactId` property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactId, ViewBag.Contacts)
```

Your POST action can be similar to your current version:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Division division)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(division).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Contacts = new SelectList(
        db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "Name", division.ContactId);

    return View(division);
}
```

Note, that it is in many cases the better practice (especially for security reasons) to use a special ViewModel instead of a database entity for your views. You could then incorporate the `Contacts` collection into your ViewModel (instead of using the `ViewBag`). To update the entity in the database you would load it and write the changed properties from the ViewModel to the entity and then save it.